# Bootstrap: how to align images to the browser border?

Tags: css, html, image, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

[illustration of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWdbQ.png)

I want some divs to have corresponding images aligned to the browser border (to the left or right of each div).

Is there a way to do it without using JS?

As for now i use the image as background for container-fluid:

```
<div class="container-fluid diamondBG">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
        <div style="display:inline-block; float:none; text-align:left;" class="col-md-9">
            Some text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.diamondBG{
    background-image: url('images/diamondLarge.png');
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

This is not a solution as the bg image is cropped to the height of the div. The div's heigh must not be specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the image with "position:absolute" and "right:0" or "left:0" in container-fluid:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="images\diamondLarge.png" style="position:absolute; right:0; margin-top:-60px;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
        <div style="display:inline-block; float:none; text-align:left;" class="col-md-9">
            Some text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

hey i'll hop it's help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ayuda</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            padding:0 !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-10 col-md-2">
      <img src="http://urdunovels.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/green-city-gandhinagar-portal-bg.jpg" width="200"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://urdunovels.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/green-city-gandhinagar-portal-bg.jpg" width="200"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-10 col-md-2">
      <img src="http://urdunovels.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/green-city-gandhinagar-portal-bg.jpg" width="200"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="http://urdunovels.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/green-city-gandhinagar-portal-bg.jpg" width="200"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is very bad practice

Comment: Thanks sittelle. This is not a solution for my problem as the image and the div's height must not be interdependent.